# How can I set up DNS to provide aliases to all my subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain, say example.com and several subdomains under it, like mail.example.com, dev.example.com and so on, of which some point to other servers, and some point to the same server with apache set up with name-based virtual hosts.

Now, I also have another domain, say xample.com which I want to use in case a user misspells the address, so I want every subdomain of xample.com to point to the same subdomain under example.com. How can I accomplish this with minimal configuration and later maintenance of the xample.com domain? I've read on wikipedia about [DNAME-records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record#DNAME_record), which seems to serve my purpose, but my DNS provider doesn't seem to support this type of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only service you're worried about is http. You could use a single wildcard DNS entry pointing to the main webserver and then from there use redirects to point the user to the corrected domain.

---

Another option is if you're willing to run your own DNS server, you can use includes to easily have the same config for all domains.

I do this and then have my DNS Provider replicate the settings from there.  Doing this adds a bit of overhead on the maintenance side though.

Comment: Thanks for answering - though it wasn't exactly the answer I was hoping for :/ A redirect via the webserver is not optimal for several reasons, and I had hoped to avoid setting up my own DNS server. I just got answer from my current DNS provider though, and it said basically the same thing. Maybe I'll try to find a provider that supports DNAME-records - hope I've understood how these work correctly...